# SSRS report with subreports: layout weird when deployed to report manager

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using a subreport (say 'child1') to create one master report (say 'parent1'). The report 'parent1' uses 15 instances of report 'child1', once for each parameter.

Up untill 10 instances, report behaviour is nice, but once I add an 11th instance, report format is getting weird. I have set `Interactive Height` to 0 for both 'child1' and 'parent1' reports. I am not sure what I'm missing here.

I have created the report in BIDS 2005, and it's working fine in BIDS. The problem only shows up when deployed in report manager. Also: exporting to Excel and PDF works just fine.

Any input on this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question and add (a) what you mean exactly by "weird" and (b) what steps you've tried so far to fix the issue?

Comment: When you say weird, do you mean that you lose some formatting once you click a few pages into the report?

Comment: thanks for reply..
a) 'weird' means for some tables, border lines gets missing. But for others, border lines gets repeted(so causes a dark border line). And also adds some extra border lines.

b) I thought the issue might be due to size. So I made 'Interactive height' to 0in for both parent and child report.
- I tried with reducing margins, but didn't work.
- Tried to increase report height. but in vain.

Comment: One noted point:- The existing report was working fine for all 15 subreports instances. But as per business requirements, I changed the dataset query to fetch more rows in tables. Since then only the report started behaving improperly. I started removing sub-reports and came to know that till 10 subreports, it is fine. As soon as, I added 11th subreport, the report format got changed for the entire report not for only 11th subreport instance.

Comment: Is the behavior present in all environments? Do you only have the problem display via HTML in Report Manager or also in BIDS or Report Builder?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually found when the report is deployed to the Report server.
You do one thing, use rectangle container for each sub report & then try out. Might help you out.